# how windows or linux resolve file rename/move/copy

Tags: java, linux, powershell, nio, apache-commons

I wonder how linux and windows resolve file rename or file move (drag and drop) at low level?
In java we have [File.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html) but I don't know how it really works ?

In apache common we have [FileUtils.moveFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

What "move file" does mean in linux and windows? Does systems put in memory file when moving/rename file then create new file and delete old one ?

Comment: you should clearly read about low level things in a file system resp. operating system, buffers and all the fancy memory management things. It's pretty interesting

Comment: Abstractions my friend! Java dispatches a file-system agnostic `move()` instruction to a platform-specific `FileSystemProvider` which then figures out which OS-level API to call, after which the OS figures out what kind of file system the given file resides on and then figures out the correct instruction for a `move` operation on the filesystem, which then in turn figures out how to move the bytes around on disk (usually just updates references in a file system table). IOW It's turtles all the way down

Comment: @AKSW thank you, you should share link about that :)? 
you speak about buffers/memory mangement : I still not know if I ask more work to my disk if I first read bytes from file then save it another place or it is better just move file, does thes both solicite my disk identically or ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you, that is my question i want know how system manage it, to understand if it is faster to move() OR read file bytes[] then create new file in another place, how system windows/linux manage buffers, does this solicit identically disk

Answer (score 1):

Copy and rename are different operations.

- Copy produces a new file.  It is done by copying bytes<sup>1</sup>; e.g. open files and use read / write syscalls to copy the bytes.
- Rename changes the pathname for an existing file.   It is done by a syscall that changes the metadata for a file and the source and destination directories.

There are a couple of wrinkles.

- Rename (on Linux) only works within a file system.  You cannot rename a file to a pathname in a different file system.
- There is no "move" syscall in Linux / POSIX libraries.  So (for example) the `mv` command on Linux will either rename the file, or make a copy (and delete the original), depending on where source and destination are.
- Copying a file *could* be implemented in a *lazy* way using copy-on-write.  For example, the "btrfs" supports copy-on-write, and it is possible that this functionality could be exposed to the application.

In a Java application, copy is implemented by copying the bytes of the file, and rename is implemented by calling the OS-provide rename syscall (see above).  The move verb is typically a hybrid of copy and move as above.

That is the simple version.  In practice, performance also depends on how the file system metadata is organized and stored, and on the various "tricks" that the OS uses to speed things up; e.g. caching metadata and file data in memory, read ahead / write behind, using "metadata transaction logs" to speed up metadata operations.  And there are hardware-basewd tuning tricks like putting the metadata onto storage media with higher IOPs per second than the data.   (This is particularly necessary if you are dealing with file systems with tens of millions of files ...)

---

<sup>1 - Actually, opening a file and creating a new one both involve reading and writing metadata, but this only happens once per file copied.  By contrast, if you are copying a file, you typically have to write (and possibly read) all disk blocks for the file.  For a large file, the reads and writes will dominate the metadata operations.</sup>

Comment: thank you, for copy this is OK to understand it put bytes in memory then create new file, but what about "move"  you said : no move on linux because everything is file it almost always rename it (metadata) but what about windows, if in java we call move() does it try to rename ? or it do copy-on-write? im not sure windows is able to rename only metadata to move file from c:/x/x/x/c.pdf to c:/y/y/y.pdf just renaming metadata (in same filesystem) and however when I drag and drop it seems faster than copy+paste or im dreaming

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think it will be the same.  Cross-filesystem renames are not possible.  Drag and drop is a "move".  Copy and paste is a "copy".